# Git: How to return from 'detached HEAD' state

Tags: git

If one would checkout a branch:

`git checkout 760ac7e`

from e.g. `b9ac70b`, how can one go back to the last known head `b9ac70b` without knowing its SHA1?

Answer (score 539, accepted):

If you remember which branch was checked out before (e.g. `master`) you could simply

```
git checkout master
```

to get out of *detached HEAD* state.

Generally speaking: `git checkout <branchname>` will get you out of that.

If you don't remember the last branch name, try

```
git checkout -
```

This also tries to check out your last checked out branch.

Comment: `git checkout -` - killer feature!

Comment: If you don't do a `git checkout -b new_branch_name` do you lose the commits made while in detached HEAD state?

Comment: @jocassid Yes you do. They are present for a while but when `git gc` is run, they are removed forever. You can watch them with `git reflog` as long as they are still there.

Comment: won't you lose any commits/changes you made in detached HEAD if you do this?  Isn't this a better way? https://stackoverflow.com/a/61489179/13087176

Comment: @tipsyboopenstein correct. jocassid already mentioned this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11801071/git-how-to-return-from-detached-head-state/11801199#comment94072848_11801199

Comment: seems like such a caveat needs to be at the top of this answer, losing work sucks

Comment: Doesn't help because _i don't want to go back to the previous branch_in my case _i want to use the new branch_

Comment: @dimpiax FWIW `cd -` would also take you to the previous directory

Comment: @Honey yes, I knew about it, but didn't try for checkout, the same works for `git switch -`

Comment: @dimpiax lol. I didn’t know there was a `git switch`

Comment: @Honey `switch` and `restore` were introduced from Git v2.23

Comment: In some versions of git, `git checkout master` no longer works, but `git checkout -` does.

Comment: For me `git checkout -` didn't work. `git checkout <branch-name>` did work. However, as mentioned above, `git switch -` is the preferred way to "undo" the operation and get back to normal.

Answer (score 21):

Use `git reflog` to find the hashes of previously checked out commits.

A shortcut command to get to your last checked out branch (not sure if this work correctly with detached HEAD and intermediate commits though) is `git checkout -`

Answer (score 15):

You may have made some new commits in the `detached HEAD` state. I believe if you do as other answers advise:

```
git checkout master
# or
git checkout -
```

then you may lose your commits!! 
Instead, you may want to do this:

```
# you are currently in detached HEAD state
git checkout -b commits-from-detached-head
```

and then merge `commits-from-detached-head` into whatever branch you want, so you don't lose the commits.

Comment: In some versions of git, `git checkout master` no longer works, but `git checkout -` does.

Comment: This solved my issue: 
`# you are currently in detached HEAD state
git checkout -b commits-from-detached-head`
Then I did
`git checkout <the branch you want to merge into>
git merge commits-from-detached-head`

Answer (score 8):

I had this edge case, where I checked out a previous version of the code in which my file directory structure was different:

```
git checkout 1.87.1                                    
warning: unable to unlink web/sites/default/default.settings.php: Permission denied
... other warnings ...
Note: checking out '1.87.1'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. 
Example:

  git checkout -b <new-branch-name>

HEAD is now at 50a7153d7... Merge branch 'hotfix/1.87.1'
```

In a case like this you may need to use --force (when you know that going back to the original branch and discarding changes is a safe thing to do).

`git checkout master` did not work:

```
$ git checkout master
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
web/sites/default/default.settings.php
... other files ...
```

`git checkout master --force` (or `git checkout master -f`) worked:

```
git checkout master -f
Previous HEAD position was 50a7153d7... Merge branch 'hotfix/1.87.1'
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
```

Answer (score 1):

In general: `git checkout <branch*>` (`git checkout master` is a special case).

**from which we (accidentally) detached a commit (using `git checkout <commit_hash>`)*

Answer (score 1):

`git switch master` to switch to the "master" branch.
`git switch -` to switch back to the previous branch.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone has the same edge case as me: I have a branch called `test` and was trying to make a branch called `test/my-experimental-feature`. That confused git because it thought I was referring to a branch that already exists. I changed it to `test--my-experimental-feature` and it worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

Since GitHub no longer uses master as the default branch for new repositories.
`git checkout master` didn't work for me.

What worked was: 
`git checkout main`

Answer (score -2):

`git checkout main`

This is the only thing that worked in my case.  Everybody else is a hack.

Comment: there are other possiblities, you can check out any branch not just master.

Comment: answer is flat out wrong